# What is the different between the self.xxx and calling xxx directly in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c

For example, I have a UIViewController, and have a value:

```
NSString *testString;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *testString;
```

in the .m:

```
@synthesize testString;
```

And what is the different between these two lines of code:

```
testString = @"something";
self.testString = @"something";
```

Comment: You'd better use `copy` instead of `retain` for `NSString` type instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case assigns  new value to `testString`, you are accessing `testString` directly:

```
testString = @"something";
```

In the second case:

```
self.testString = @"something";
```

You are calling `setter` generated by calling `@synthesize testString` and the fact that it's a property.

The second case calls generated `[aUIViewControllerObject setTestString: @"something"]` in which the `@"something"` `NSString` is retained (because the `testString` property is declared with `retain` parameter), the old value is `autoreleased` or `released` and the new value is assigned to `testString`.

Answer (score 0):

`self.testString = @"something";` implicitly calls `setTestString:` method. In your case it means following:

```
-(void) setTestString: (NSString*) newString
{
    if (testString != newString)
    {
        [testString release];
        testString = [newString retain];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in non-ARC code there is a significant difference if you're declaring properties as `retain` or `copy`. in these two cases, there's a bit more going on behind the scenes when you call `self.property`. very simplistically, `retain` does something like:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)newFoo {
  [newFoo retain];
  [foo release];
  foo = newFoo;
}
```

and with copy it'd be something like:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)newFoo {
  NSString *oldFoo = foo;
  foo = [newFoo copy];
  [oldFoo release];
}
```

}